# How to find correspondences among the features detected in two images?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, correspondence

I have two planar images taken from different viewpoints. I implemented feature detectors like Harris, Shi-Tomasi, ORB, FAST, MSER, etc. The descriptors I used are ORB and BRISK and feature matching technique s are FLANN and BRUTE. A lot of features were detected ranging from 1000-3000. I want to find the correspondences between two images. Everything I have done is in OpenCV Python. I don't necessarily want to understand the math. I already have the homography. Now I just want a code for calculating the correspondences.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Not quite sure, what exactly you are asking, since Flann based feature matcher is already the algorithm you use to find correspondences between images. [OpenCV already provides an implementation of the algorithm in their documentation.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#:~:text=the%20result%20below%3A-,FLANN%20based%20Matcher,than%20BFMatcher%20for%20large%20datasets.)

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @RolandDeschain I did use Flann. But I thought its a feature matcher? Are correspondences and features matched the same?

Comment: @moosehead42 I used the code in the url below to compute the homography. Sorry for not writing in the proper format by way. I still dont know how to insert links properly in the comment.   https://blog.ekbana.com/skew-correction-using-corner-detectors-and-homography-fda345e42e65

Comment: @DaisyNarjiary yes, you use ORB, FAST, SIFT,...etc to find features in images. If you have two images with a list of features, you can use the flann based feature matcher to find matches, which means features that appear in both images. I wouldn't know what else could be meant with correspondences.